# PHP include file.php having CSS issues

Tags: php, html, css

I have a index PHP page where I include all PHP files like `index.php?page=example`. All pages are in another folder, here is the structure:

```
public_html/index.php
public_html/css/style.php
public_html/pages/
```

Index calls the CSS file from `css/style.php`.
Pages are called from `index.php` like (`include pages/example.php`) using GET function.

If I run `index.php` I get no problems with CSS, if I run only the included page like `example.php` I get CSS problems because the CSS is in `index.php` and obviously will not show the CSS correct.

But when I run the `index.php` and include the `index.php?page=example` then the index CSS show correct but the classes from the included pages does not work...

I suppose the include will only import the code but it seems like something is wrong with the server or I am doing something wrong?

Here is a example code of what I am using. This is index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"> 
  </head>
  <body>
        <?php 
        include('pages/example.php'); 
        ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Index.php all css classes works fine but the style class from the included pages does not work they are just not styled

Comment: How you path to css look in style.php? /css/style.css or css/style.css?

Comment: @Happy Knight Add your `index.php` code...

Comment: You cannot include css files. css files are referenced from the client side inside the html head. The reference you put in there has nothing to do with how you include or call you php files.

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

Comment: Edited my code question with a example

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">  try like this.

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't write your css code in a php file. Better create a css file and put your style directives in there. You can include css styles best by following conventions, create a basic html template like the following and link to your css file and include the php in there.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="part/to/file.css"> <!-- link your stylesheet here -->
  </head>
  <body>
        <?php 
        include('path/to/file.php'); // include your php code here
        ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think this answer will help full try that

Comment: Edited my question, added your code as example because is the same thing. And is not working. Maybe because css and pages are in separated folders?

Comment: Completely agree with you and gave a thumbs up, but there are many reasons for which he could want a dynamic php stylesheet, so perhaps that should also be addressed. @michael

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have header("Content-type: text/css"); as your first line in php file so it renders correctly as css. Then do not include the file. Instead refrence to it like a normal css file only change the .css to .php.   `<link rel="stylesheet" href="part/to/file.php">`. That should get you working. I am assuming your pulling data from a database to fill in your css, so make sure it is format correctly. Do not use something like `.headertext{
    color:<?=$row['headercolor'];?>;` . Instead declare it in php tags.  `$color= $row['headercolor'];` . Then in css part of php file call that variable.                                                            `.headertext{
    color:<?=$headercolor?>;`. Hope that helps